# pandas.reorder_levels with only one index

Tags: pandas, indexing

Pandas offers a feature to reorder index with the reorder_index function :

```
pandas.DataFrame({"A" : [1, 2, 3], "B" : [4,5,6], "C" : [7,8,9]}).set_index(["A", "B"]).reorder_levels(["B", "A"])
```

However it doesn't seem to work with single-indexed DataFrames :

```
pandas.DataFrame({"A" : [1, 2, 3], "B" : [4,5,6]}).set_index("A").reorder_levels(["A"])
```

Am I doing something incorrectly ?

PS : I know it doesn't make sens to reorder the Index with only one index, however it's a border effect and I usually tend to avoid un-necessary if statements for code clarity.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Does it makes sense to reorder_levels if you only have 1?

Comment: It's a generic code, I'm added a bypass to see weather there is more that 1 Index in the MultiIndex, but let say it's a border effect.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the following is *equivalent* to reordering:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6], "C": [7, 8, 9]}).set_index(["A", "B"])
print(df.reset_index().set_index(['B', 'A']))
```

**Output**

```
     C
B A   
4 1  7
5 2  8
6 3  9
```

And it works with a single index:

```
odf = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]}).set_index("A")
print(odf)
```

**Output**

```
   B
A   
1  4
2  5
3  6
```

Comment: I thought about it but the index is long_timed defined. I can always remove the index and rebuild it, but not the best in term of performance